# PHP: can't change number of arguments in static function of same name in subclass

Tags: php

I am wondering whether I can create a static function in a subclass with the same name as a static function in a superclass, but with a different number of arguments. I have tried this, but get an error.

Anyone know why PHP is coded to give this error? I am using the latest version of PHP, PHP 8.0.2, in TermUX on Android.

Anyone know or have any suggestions, even from a software engineering standpoint, how to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

```
<?php
 
class Foo {
 
  public static function greet($name) {
    echo "Hi $name. This is Foo.\n";
  }
 
}
 
class Bar {
 
  public static function greet($name){
    echo "Hi $name. This is Bar.\n";
  }
 
} 
 
class Baz extends Bar {
    // changing number of arguments in static function of same name in subclass
     // generates: Fatal error: Declaration of Baz::greet($name, $name2) 
    //must be compatible with Bar::greet($name)
  public static function greet($name, $name2){
    echo "Hi $name and $name2. This is Baz.\n";
  }
}
 
Foo::greet("David");
Bar::Greet("Anne");
Baz::Greet("Bob", "Sue");
?>
```

Comment: _I have tried this, but get an error_ That would seem to answer your question. Anyway, please ALWAYS show us the code you are talking about. It help s us to understand the question if nothing else, [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I fixed it. Take a  look at how I did it for next time :)

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the error message, PHP doesn't allow you to change the signature of a method when overriding a method.

Comment: Got it, just had to add ``` delimiters.

Comment: As to the error, why can't I change the signature? What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: That's just the way PHP works. You can work around this by using `__call()` and `__callStatic()` depending on the specific use case.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please illustrate this with an example? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter static method or not.

The php language with each subsequent version becomes more "typed". In previous version 7.- you will get warning instead. By the way php doesn't have "Method overloading" like in other languages.
You can use args param, like this:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public static function greet(...$args) {
        echo "Hi $args[0]. This is Foo.\n";
    }

}

class Bar {

    public static function greet(...$args){
        echo "Hi $args[0]. This is Bar.\n";
    }

}

class Baz extends Bar {

    public static function greet(...$args){
        echo "Hi " . implode(' and ', $args) . ". This is Baz.\n";
    }
}

Foo::greet("David");
Bar::Greet("Anne");
Baz::Greet("Bob", "Sue");
```

Or use array of params (or class, contained them)

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public static function greet($params) {
        echo "Hi " . $params['name1'] . ". This is Foo.\n";
    }

}

class Bar {

    public static function greet($params){
        //you can use reset ;)
        echo "Hi " . reset($params) . ". This is Bar.\n";
    }

}

class Baz extends Bar {

    public static function greet($params){
        echo "Hi " . implode(' and ', $params) . " This is Baz.\n";
    }
}

Foo::greet(["name1" => "David"]);
Bar::Greet(["name1" => "Anne"]);
Baz::Greet(["name1" => "Bob", "name2" => "Sue"]);
```